# How to get the show / hide effect by scrolling (up / down)

Tags: jquery

My website has a menu bar, and I want it to hide when user scrolls down, and appear when user scrolls up.

I tried to use the `scrollTop` function, and I found the code for adding the `scrollBottom` function. Unfortunately, it does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.fn.scrollBottom = function(scroll) {
        if (typeof scroll === 'number') {
            window.scrollTo(0, $(document).height() - $(window).height() - scroll);
            return $(document).height() - $(window).height() - scroll;
        } else {
            return $(document).height() - $(window).height() - $(window).scrollTop();
        }
    }
    $(document).scrollTop(function() {
        $('header').fadeIn(200);
    });
    $(document).scrollBottom(function() {
        $('header').fadeOut(200);
    });

});
```

I'd like to get a bar effect like this:
[image: expected output]

Answer (score 1):

`.scrollTop` is not meant to be used in that way. Rather, it is an element property that returns the distance the element is from the top.

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop

I think what you want instead is to add an event listener (in jQuery `.on()`) for scroll and then conditionally fire the functions you want inside the listener callback. Assuming your scroll detection function correctly returns true/false:

```
function scrolledFunc() {
  // returns true if page is scrolled
}

$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  if (scrolledFunc) {
    $('header').fadeIn(200);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have already found a solution.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var zero = 0;  
    $(document).on('scroll', function(){
        $('header').toggleClass('hide', $(window).scrollTop() > zero);
        zero = $(window).scrollTop();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("return-to-top").style.display = "none";

$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(this).scrollTop() >= 10)
    {
      document.getElementById("return-to-top").style.display = "";
    }
    else 
    {
      document.getElementById("return-to-top").style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="scroll-to-top" id="return-to-top">
      <a href="javascript:"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></a>
  </div>
```

Here is another example, hope it'd help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example, demonstrating how to detect if the user scroll direction is going down or up, and showing/hiding a menu bar as appropriate.

```js
var lastpos=0, lastScrollDir='up';
$(window).scroll(function(){
  let curpos = $(window).scrollTop();
  let scrollDir = (curpos > lastpos) ? 'down' : 'up';
  if (scrollDir !== lastScrollDir && scrollDir == 'down'){
     lastScrollDir = scrollDir;
     $('#mnu').animate({
        height: '0px'
     },700);
  }else if (scrollDir !== lastScrollDir && scrollDir == 'up') {
     lastScrollDir = scrollDir;
     $('#mnu').animate({
        height: '40px'
     },700);
  }
  
  $('#msg').html(scrollDir + ' / ' + curpos);
  lastpos = curpos;
});
```

```css
#mnu{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100vw;height:40px;background:black;color:white;}
#content{width:100vw;min-height:200vh;}
  .flex-parent{display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;flex-direction:column;}
  .flex-child{flex:1;}
  .flex-child:nth-child(1){margin-top:80px;}
  
#msg{position:fixed;top:0;right:0;padding:10px;text-align:center;background:wheat;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mnu">Menu Bar</div>
<div id="content" class="flex-parent">
  <div class="flex-child">Content goes here</div>
  <div class="flex-child">Content goes here</div>
  <div class="flex-child">Content goes here</div>
  <div class="flex-child">Content goes here</div>
  <div class="flex-child">Content goes here</div>
  <div class="flex-child">Content goes here</div>
  <div class="flex-child">Content goes here</div>
</div>
<div id="msg"></div>
```